# Installing py2deb for python2 and python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

After I run `pip install py2deb` and `pip3 install py2deb`. The py2deb packages are installed under different paths:

```
Location: ~/.local/lib/python2/site-packages
Location: ~/.local/lib/python3/site-packages
```

But there is one bin

```
~/.local/bin/py2deb
```

Can it be installed with different binary names `py2deb` and `py2deb3`?

Other packages like nose are installed with bin names like `nosetests, nosetests3`.

Offcourse I can create a symlink or create another file. But is there any better solution or am i missing something?

Comment: Packages that install version-dependent scripts do that themselves. Said `nosetest` [does this in its `setup.py`](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/7c26ad1e6b7d308cafa328ad34736d34028c122a/setup.py#L33). Most packages don't do that so they only install one version of their scripts. You need to copy/rename installed scripts manually right after installation and there is no simple way to work around it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation